# Differential Equation using Laplace transformation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a problem solving this differential equation using Laplace transformation.

$y'' -9y=0 , \ y(0)=1 , \ y'(0)=0$

Comment: Have you tried applying $\mathcal{L}\{y^\prime\}=sY-y(0)$ and $\mathcal{L}\{y^{\prime\prime}\}=s\mathcal{L}\{y^\prime\}-y^\prime(0)$?

Comment: Also clasically solvable with approach $y =ce^{\lambda x}$. Characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-9 = 0$, giving $\lambda = \pm 3$, then $y = c_1e^{3x} + c_2e^{-3x}$. Pluggin in the two intial conditions $y(0)=1, y'(0)=0$ gives $c_1=c_2 = \frac{1}{2}$ and so $y = \frac{e^{3x}+e^{-3x}}{2} = \cosh(3x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Laplace transform, we have $$\mathcal{L}\{y'\}(s) =sY(s) - y(0)$$
And $$\mathcal{L}\{y''\}(s) =s^2Y(s)- sy(0) - y'(0)$$
This transforms the differential equation
$$y''−9y=0, \quad y(0)=1, \;y'(0)=0$$
Into
$$(s^2Y(s)- sy(0) - y'(0))−9Y(s)= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (s^2Y(s)- s\cdot 1 - 0)−9Y(s)= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow (s^2Y(s)- s)−9Y(s)= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y(s)(s^2-9)-s= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y(s)(s^2-9)= s$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y(s) = \frac{s}{s^2-9}$$
The right term can be identified as the laplace transform of the $\cosh(at)$ function (http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf), since
$$\mathcal{L}\{\cosh(at)\}(s) = \frac{s}{s^2-a^2}$$
And hence here $a=3$ and the inverse tranform of $Y(s)$ is 
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}(t) = \cosh(3t)$$ 
And the differential equation is solved.